# Non empty Iterator turned empty after printing

Tags: scala, iterator

In scala, I read a file using getLines which returned a non-empty Iterator. Then I printed the lines using for loop. After that when I tried to print again it says empty Iterator. Can someone explain?

```
scala> c
res1: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> println(c)
non-empty iterator

scala> for ( line <- c) println(line)

insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (1, 'ABBA', 'WATERLOO', 0);
insert into songlist (id, artist, title, numone) values (2, 'ABBA',.............

scala> var d = for ( line <- c) println(line)
d: Unit = ()
scala> c
res8: Iterator[String] = empty iterator
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is very expected behaviour of `Iterator` because as you keep traversing the `Iterator` the state changes. (Thus `Iterator` is mutable)

```
scala> Iterator("order1", "order2", "order3")
res8: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> res8.foreach(println)
order1
order2
order3

scala> res8
res10: Iterator[String] = empty iterator
```

Read the [Iterator docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Iterator.html)

> It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise,
>   one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it.

If you want to iterate multiple times, convert to immutable datastructure like list or sequence.

example,

```
scala> Iterator("order1", "order2", "order3", "order4")
res18: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> res18.toList
res19: List[String] = List(order1, order2, order3, order4)

scala> res19.foreach(println)
order1
order2
order3
order4

scala> res19.foreach(println)
order1
order2
order3
order4
```

or `toSeq`,

```
scala> Iterator("order1", "order2", "order3", "order4")
res23: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> res23.toSeq
res24: Seq[String] = Stream(order1, ?)

scala> res24.foreach(println)
order1
order2
order3
order4

scala> res24.foreach(println)
order1
order2
order3
order4
```